# Select query with minus and sum

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 3 tables: `user`, `project` and `tracking`. Here is the table `tracking`:

| id | user_id | project_id | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 32 | 12 | 8 | 12 |
| 124 | 32 | 12 | 13 | 17 |
| 125 | 77 | 63 | 10 | 11 |
| 126 | 77 | 12 | 13 | 17 |
| 127 | 15 | 12 | 15 | 17 |
| 128 | 24 | 12 | 8 | 10 |

The fields `start_time` and `end_time` are relevant to working time (8 to 12, 13 to 17).
Every day, a user can contribute to many projects, of course.

Now I would like to get the project info as below:

| Project name | Total tracking time |
| --- | --- |
| First | 1860 |
| Second | 3122 |

In which, `Total tracking time` is the sum of all the time the project members have been tracked as contributor.

How I can get this result with a `select` query? The following doesn't work.

```sql
SELECT *,
  SUM(SELECT *, (end_time - start_time) AS tracking_time,
    FROM tracking
    WHERE project_id = project.id
  )) AS tracking_time,
FROM project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT p.*, t.tracking_time
FROM project p
JOIN (
  SELECT project_id, SUM(end_time - start_time) AS tracking_time
  FROM tracking
  GROUP BY project_id
) t ON p.project_id = t.project_id
```

Or a corrected query, as you tried, will also work:

```
SELECT *,
  (SELECT SUM(end_time - start_time) AS tracking_time
   FROM tracking
   WHERE project_id = project.id
  ) AS tracking_time
FROM project
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column names of the `project` table, I think the following query can help:

```
SELECT 
    name as 'Project name', 
    SUM(end_time - start_time) as 'Total tracking time'
FROM project p JOIN tracking t
ON p.id = t.project_id
GROUP BY name
```